# Intermediate Representations using Javacc

Tags: javacc

I am trying to write the Intermediate Representations for expressions like:

```
a= 1+2-3*5/6 
a= 1+2-3
a= 5/6+3
```

I am pretty new to `JavaCC` but I have basic knowledge about generating an `AST` using `JJTree`. I haven't made a separate class for `IR`, or implemented it with `JJTree`. I have written the grammar and tried to implement `IR` right in it.

The code is:

```
// E -> T (addop T)*
// T -> F (mulop F)*
// F -> intlit | "(" E ")"

SKIP :
{
" "
| "\t"
| "\n"
| "\r"
}

TOKEN :
{
  < ADDOP :
    "+"
  | "-" >
| < MULOP :
"*"
| "/" >
| < INTLIT : ([ "0"-"9" ])+ >
}

String S() :
{
  String s;
}
{
  s = E()
{
return "a=" + s;
 }
}

String E() :
{
  String left, right;
  Token op;
}
{
  left = T()
  (
    op = < ADDOP > right = T()
    {
      left = ("t" + count++) + ": " + left + op.image + right + "\t";
    }
  )*
  {
    return left;
  }
}

String T() :
{
  String left, right;
  Token op;
}
{
  left = F()
  (
    op = < MULOP > right = F()
    {
      left = ("t" + count++) + ": " + left + op.image + right;
    }
  )*
  {
    return left;
  }
}

String F() :
{
  String s;
  Token t;
}
{
  t = < INTLIT >
  {
    return t.image;
  }
}
```

My code works fine for Expressions like `1+2*3;` or `1-2/4;` where a particular operator is not repeated in an expression.

It would give a messy output for expressions where one out of `+ -` or `* /` is repeating or `+ -` or `/ *`, both are included in expression. e.g. `1+2-4` (+ - both included), `1-2-3` (minus repeating) so on. *(See attached [picture for output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0e7bq.png))*

My questions are:

How can I eliminate the above mentioned problems?

If my way of doing `IR` in Grammar file/class is not appropriate then **what is a better way to perform `IR` in `JavaCC`**?**

Comment: For an input of `1-2-3`, exactly what output would you want?

Comment: Likewise for `(1-2)-3`.

Comment: for 1-2-3 I would want t0: 1-2, t1: t0-3, a=t1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is to use a string buffer, output stream, or mutable list to accumulate the quadruples and return the value or intermediate representing the value of each nonterminal as a result.

E.g., for example

```
String E(StringBuffer buf) :
{
  String left, right;
  Token op;
}
{
  left = T(buf)
  (
       op = < ADDOP > right = T(buf)
      {
        left = buildQuad( buf, left, op.image, right ) ;
      }
  )*
  {
    return left;
  }
}
```

where buildQuad is defined as

```
String buildQuad( StringBuffer buf, String left, String op, String right )
{
    String register = "t" + count++
    buf.append( register + ": " + left + op + right + "\t" );
    return register ;
}
```